# Python webdriver script OK from console but won't start as an Upstart service

Tags: python, linux, bash, selenium-webdriver, upstart

I need to run a Python script that uses Selenium webdriver:

```
import platform
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

driver = None

if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    print("Initializing browser for chrome...")
    DISPLAY = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    DISPLAY.start()
    print("Started display")
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    print("Done init chrome")
    connected = True
else:
    try:
        print("Starting firefox...")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        connected = True
    except:
        print("Could not connect through firefox")

if driver:
    print("driver ok")
    driver.quit()
    print("All ok")
```

The script runs OK from console:

```
sudo ~/environments/scrapers/bin/python test_webdriver.py
Initializing browser for chrome...
Started display
Done init chrome
driver ok
All ok
```

But gives a WebDriverException error if trying to run using an exec stanza with Upstart:

```
Initializing browser for chrome...
Started display
...
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.8.0-58-generic x86_64)
```

I've added possibly absent paths in the upstart script, like this

```
env PYTHON_HOME=/home/rsa-key-20161031/environments/scrapers
env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PYTHON_HOME:$PATH
env ENV=production
env DISPLAY=:10
chdir /home/user/project
console log
exec $PYTHON_HOME/bin/python test_webdriver.py
```

With no effect. Search for error doesn't give anything specific to this.
Any insight on how to get this working is much appreciated.

**Update:**
My current solution is to use Cron since it doesn't seem to have problems using Xvfb. I'd still very much like to know if it is possible to run a webdriver task as a service. I also tried using Selenium as remote webdriver, with same negative results (Chrome exits after apparently not being able to connect to a virtual display)

Comment: Upstart has no X-Windows session with which to start Chrome. Upstart and other Linux service management systems (systemd,sysVinit) are not designed for use with services that rely on a GUI.

Comment: Thanks; does the fact that I use Pyvirtualdisplay/start Xvfb as a separate process change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confronted with a similar situation, while I configured pytest to run with selenium and firefox webdriver.

As a solution you could install `xvfb` i.e. in debian

```
sudo apt install xvfb
```

Now you could adjust your upstart file after the `exec` position, so that xvfb is called with your script as a parameter

```
xvfb-run --server-num=10 <script>
```

This way `xvfb` is started in front of your script.

Comment: Good idea, thanks; while trying this out; upon start Xvfb-run gives the following error: `/usr/bin/xvfb-run: mktemp: not found`, while mktemp is present in the system. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @AlexBausk Glad to hear that it almost works. I guess that `mktemp` is not part of your PATH variable; so type `which mktemp` (in my case `/bin`) and add the path with a colon i.e `env PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:...`

Comment: Wow, it actually works now. I'm incredibly thankful for your help! This has been bugging me to no end